# Running external Python file from VSCode extension

Tags: python, vscode-extensions

I want to create a VSCode extension that will validate a .yml file in real time, as it's written.
My validation functions are in Python.
Can I run the validation file as is from the extension without having to rewrite Python functions in JS?

Answer (score 0):

What you might do next is just,

1. Write a command line linter in Python.
2. Integrate this linter with VSCode via an extension.

There are already tons of VSCode linter extensions on GitHub that you can use as examples, and I wrote [a blog post](https://blog.lextudio.com/how-a-visual-studio-code-linter-works-681c8388b0ea) to summarize my experience.